# How can i get a token expiry when i authenticate to Salesforce using OAuth2?

Tags: salesforce

I have set up a connected app with the following OAuth scopes

```
Access the identity URL service (id, profile, email, address, phone)
Manage user data via APIs (api)
Manage user data via Web browsers (web)
Perform requests at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
Access custom permissions (custom_permissions)
```

I first authenticate using the following

```
     $"{this.ServiceUrl}/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={this.ClientId}&redirect_uri=<HOST_NAME>/SalesForce/MySFCallback";
```

this presents me with the Salesforce login screen and once i have successfully logged in , I am returned back to my web page and then i try to
get a token as follows:

Using the code value returned from the callback , I call

```
        var client = new RestClient(Uri + "/token");
        var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("code", code, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientsecret, ParameterType.GetOrPost);            
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", $"{callbackUri}", ParameterType.GetOrPost);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I get back the JSON response , but there is no expiry for the token.

How can i get an expiry for the token ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/73512/799 ? Very good answers there.

In a pinch your administrator could try creating a custom number field on User based on user's profile and then expose it to you as a [custom attribute](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_edit_custom_attributes.htm&type=5) (you'd see the extra field in the base64-encoded `id_token` piece, if you requested this `response_type`).

But really admin can:

1. terminate sessions at any time (Setup -> Session Management),
2. revoke your connected app's access
3. other things can kick in like you switching IPs (from office vpn to home network or cellular data plan) and company having Setup -> Session Settings -> Lock sessions to IP from which they originated...

So at best this thing would be indicative timeout.

Try to code it defensively based on refresh tokens like in [sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox)'s [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/73550/799)